# Prediction Model on categorical y with more than 20 levels

Tags: r, prediction, discrete-data

My goal is to predict y, but my dependent variable `y` has more than `20 levels`. I dont think multi-nomial model would be a good choice ? Any suggestions or pointers on what modeling methodology I should explore for this problem is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Ordinal logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) models are often used when $y$ is ordered - proportional odds being the most common assumption. But why don't you think a multinomial model would be a good choice?

Comment: @Scortchi, data is not Ordinal. It just seems odd running a multinomial model on a `y` that has so many levels. This maybe due to my inexperience on this issue.

Comment: Just wondered. I can't think of anything specifically contra-indicating multinomial regression in this case, though of course you'll have a lot of coefficients to estimate & over-fitting'll become a problem sooner than with fewer levels. If you're classifying rather than just predicting the probability of class membership, then think about @hxd1011's point. Is each of the more than 380 possible misclassifications equally bad?

Comment: @Scortchi Thanks Scortchi now I am confident about my instincts on this topic

Answer (score 1):

Predicting a discrete outcome with too many levels is a hard problem. Usually people do **one vs. others** approach, where you build many models and each model can detect one specific level of the output.

Here is why: Think about you have a 100 side-dice, and **you know the true distribution**. Where $P(S_1)=0.1$, and $P(S_2)=P(S_3)=P(S_{100})=0.9/99=0.009090$. Now what you do with [Maximum a posteriori estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation)? You will always guess you get the first side $S_1$, since it has largest probability comparing to others. However you will get wrong $90\%$ of the times!!

For details, please check my answers in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213017/to-maximize-the-chance-of-correctly-guessing-the-result-of-a-coin-flip-should-i/213032#213032)