# Topic Modeling: How many documents "belong" to a topic?

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

A frequent question that arises when I present results of topic modeling to novices is: "How many documents belong to topic x?".

As topic modeling is probabilistic, I hesitate giving absolute frequencies as an answer. But "mean document-topic-probability" is nothing people unexperienced in topic modeling can deal with.

How would you determine the number of documents per topic? Using a cut-off in document-topic-probability?

Comment: Since I had some situations where a clear number of documents per topic was wished (e.g., share of female authors per topic), I ended up with the following approach:
**Select all docs with document-topic-probability > .5**
Although I agree with @haitao-du, doing it the Bayesian way (mean document-topic-probability of women vs. men) is sometimes hard to communicate. So selecting docs that _mainly_ address the topic might be a workaround for those situations, of course accompanied by stressing the resulting loss of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question related to membership assignment and have little thing to do with topic modeling.

Assign a membership based on probability is a question frequently asked. See here as an example.

[To maximize the chance of correctly guessing the result of a coin flip, should I always choose the most probable outcome?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213017/to-maximize-the-chance-of-correctly-guessing-the-result-of-a-coin-flip-should-i/213032#213032)

We can assign the membership based on [Maximum a posteriori estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) or others.

Think about two examples:

- Suppose there are only $2$ topics, we can easily set the threshold to be $0.5$.
- Suppose there are $100$ topics, and the probability distribution for **a given document** is $[0.1, 0.9/99, \cdots, 0.9/99]$. How do we assign the membership? If we assign it to be topic 1 (which is the MAP estimation) but we will get 90% wrong !

So, the answer is just use the probability (Bayesian way), and do not use a threshold to assign membership.